# PHP redirect - content cannot be displayed in a frame

Tags: php, redirect

I have an PHP with some trouble redirecting form my page to another page (same domain). Let's say I try to see if the user has access tot the page and if not, after a message, I want to redirect him to the main page.

I tried with

```
header('Location: ' . $url);
die();
```

Also I tried with something like this:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
$result = curl_exec ($ch);
```

But I get an

```
This content cannot be displayed in a frame   
To help protect the security of information you enter into this website, the publisher of this content does not allow it to be displayed in a frame.
```

Can you please help me with this?
Thanks!

Comment: How have you defined `$url` in your first example? It sould work normally..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

header('Location: ' . $url);  -- should be placed before any other output in a php page and it will redirect your page immediately using http headers and your document or the rest of the output WILL NOT be displayed in the browser.
So if you want to show a message to your user before redirecting, from a page you should either consider using js or meta redirect from the browser side.

1. Meta Redirect (Not recommended by W3C)
   <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/" />
2. Javascript

<script>

```
setTimeout(function(){
window.location="./mynewpage.html";
},5000);
```

</script>

<noscript>You do not have enough access permission to access this page, Please <a href="./mynewpage.html">Click Here</a> to continue
 <noscript>

Ok, to disable going back, you can force the browser to revalidate the page, by setting

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0 ");
```

Comment: I have something like this:
<?php
if(!$found){
$url = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$contextPath.'vrisk';
echo '<script language="javascript">';
echo 'alert("You do not have acess for this!")';
echo '</script>';
}
?>
How can I put this <noscript> thing into my message somehow, not to allow the user to go back on that page, or after he press the OK button of the AlertBox...

Comment: @MiG you can set window.location after alert() to redirect, plus try the cache control update on answer, hope it helps, noscript : is a fail safe for js disabled browsers, you can place it inside body...

Comment: I put something loke this: echo '<script language="javascript">';
                                echo 'alert("You do not have acess for this!\n'.$url.'")';
                                echo '</script>';
                                echo '<script language="javascript">';
                                echo 'window.location.href="'.$url.'";';
                                echo '</script>';
but I get "This content cannot be displayed in a frame" - fter I press OK in alert box

Comment: you use an iframe ?!,, is it ok for you to redirect the complete document, like using, window.top.location.href = "test.html";  (also you can use 
 target="_top" attribute for noscript anchor to load in top level parent)

Comment: by the way,  
echo 'alert("You do not have acess for this!")';
echo 'window.location.href="'.$url.'"; can be placed in a single script tag

Answer (score 1):

Open Internet Explorer and select "Tools > Internet options"

Select the "Privacy " tab and select the "Advanced" button.

An "Advanced Privacy Settings" window will open.

Tick the "Override automatic cookie handling" button and "OK" back to Internet Explorer.

Now try your problem website.